# How do I add a remote desktop user in windows 10 in Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-10

I setup a Windows 10 virtual machine in Microsoft Azure.  When I set it up, it automatically added me as an administrator with remote desktop access.  I want to add a new user.  I tried adding a user in Windows 10 but it only allows to add a windows live email address.  I did that but the user is not able to login using their windows live email and password.  How do I add the user?  Is it through Windows 10 or through Azure or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup RDP for Azure you need to install Azure PowerShell. You will need to run the command below.

```
Enable-AzureServiceProjectRemoteDesktop
```

Then you will be prompted to create a username and password. When you are done entering the information you should be able to connect to your Azure instance and the login with the username and password you just set.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-enable-remote-desktop/?cdn=disable